# Copying CSS from devtools trouble

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

After Chrome update (I think) when I copy & paste CSS code from devtools to any document it suddenly goes on multiple lines.

When I try to copy and paste CSS (border-bottom: 7px solid #7c8f1e;) it's look like:

```
border-bottom: 7
px
 solid #7c8f1e;
```

**I noticed that for pixels it is possible to scroll the value. Maybe that's the problem.**

Help fix this please))

Comment: It's a bug in devtools, https://crbug.com/1259088, fixed in Canary and Chrome beta.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix won't be live for another week.

In the meantime, you can right click on the rule and select **copy rules** as a workaround as suggested here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259088